# unwanted lines in exporting a plot

Tags: plotting, export

I am trying to export the below plot

```
plot = Plot3D[Sin[x] Cos[y], {x, 0, 2 π}, {y, 0, 2 π}]
```

and

```
Export["plot.png", plot, "PNG"]
```

[image]

but my problem is related to the vertical and horizontal lines around the shape.
How can I export the plot in `png` format or any format that can be inserted by Microsoft Word (for example not PDF or EPS because they can not be inserted by Word) and in a good resolution (for example `png` is better `jpeg`) but not with an unwanted vertical and horizontal lines

Comment: I do not experience this on v10.4 under Windows 10. What version of Mathematica/OS are you using? Also, on what program did you open the image to take the screenshot you posted here? Did you try opening it with some other application?

Comment: I am using Math v 10.3, win 7. 64. I just opened it by paint for drawing some arrows for clarifying. I inserted the same picture in Word but the lines were accompanied.

Comment: so just to be clear, if you drag and drop tha produced `.png` file into the mathematica notebook, do you still see the lines in the figure produced in the notebook?

Comment: Yes the lines are sticky to the plot. I dragged and dropped to a notebook but they are still appeared

Comment: I'm not reproducing this behaviour, but it rings a bell. I'm not sure, but try doing something with `ImagePadding` or some similar options.